# Remix Error: This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created when trying to pass modifiers

Tags: solidity, remix

In the below code I can successfully deploy the "UserRegistry" contract, but when I try to deploy the "User" contract, I get the error `This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created.` Based on this [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/7womgt/error_this_contract_does_not_implement_all/), I thought I could inherit modifiers from a contract containing only modifiers. I am not seeing why I can compile this Reddit user's code but not mine as it seems to fit the same pattern.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract UserRegistry {

    address owner;

    struct user {
        uint dateAdded;
        uint repuation;
    }

    mapping(address => user) users;

    modifier IsUser(address account) {
        require(
            users[account].dateAdded != 0   
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier OwnerApproved() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner
        );
        _;
    }

     constructor(address _owner) public {
        owner = _owner;
    }
}

contract User is UserRegistry {

    event EventAddUser(address account);

    function addUser(address account) public {
        users[account].dateAdded = now;

        emit EventAddUser(account);
    }

    function updateUserRep(address _user) public IsUser(_user) OwnerApproved {
        users[_user].repuation +=  1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `User` class is not implementing the constructor. You can call the parent constructor in this way

```
constructor(address _owner) UserRegistry(_owner) public { }
```

please note that also the addUser is actually wrong. You need to create the struct

```
users[account] = user(now, 0);
```

Comment: So, does this mean that my contract UserRegistry actually has a separate users mapping from the one in the "Users" contract? By this I mean, if I were to put the "addUser" function in the "UserRegistry" contract in addition to the "Users" contract, that calling `users[address] `  in "Users" would not be the same as calling ` users[address]` in UserRegistry?

Comment: depends where the `users` is defined. if you have the same function in `UserRegistry` but you call it from `Users` contract then the latter will be executed. In solidity all functions are virtual by default, so the most derived one would be call unless you provide the contract name. The fields follow the same 'rule' so if you have another `users` mapping inside User contract it would be different than the one inside UserRegistry http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#inheritance